# Using Rcpp routines in apps submitted to shinyapps.io

Tags: c++, shiny

i have an app that does some calculations using a C++ routine and Rcpp. It runs perfectly fine when i run it locally using runApp, but is crashes (browser window goes gray) when i submit it to shinyapps.io As a check i wrote a very short C++ routine, and when i submit this one everything works fine, so the problem seems to be something in the large C++ routine. It is over 1000 lines, so i don't want to attach it here, but maybe someone has some ideas on what to check that could cause this problem?

Thanks

Wolfgang

Comment: Have you checked the output of `rsconnect::showLogs()` function?

Comment: sorry, i don't know what that means. After submitting the app to shinyapps.io there is now a folder C:\R\myshiny\Rcpptest\rsconnect\shinyapps.io\wolfgangrolke with a single .dcf file, but the info there is only when the app was submitted. Where would i find that showLogs()?

Comment: I figured out what you meant. I solved my problem. Thanks!